# Flipkart Order report or revenue report generation link needed to use with seller ID

Tags: html, hyperlink, flipkart-api

I am trying to find an API link of flipkart where IF i am logged in with credential already I can search revenue data of order by just putting link in CSV. but I don't know the link currently. I used to use it in my previous workplace. Now I can't go there but I really need it. Can anyone share me the link? I am basic familiar with coding. Was used to code in php for developing other softwares. If Possible I would like to know more API links like them. So I can directly download the data without waiting for flipkart to generate it for me.

I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.